# Wordpress 3.1.2 Permalinks Broken

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a fresh install of WordPress 3.1.2 (not upgraded but installed fresh), containing no plugins whatsoever.

I'm having what seems to be from my googling a fairly common problem, but none of the solutions I can find work for me.

I have a custom taxonomy and a custom post type running, the code from my functions.php:

```
register_post_type( 'product', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product'),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product'),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add a Product'),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product'),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Product'),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Product'),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search products' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No products found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in Trash' )
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor'
    ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'can_export' => true
));

register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Product Categories',
        'singular_name' => 'Product Category',
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Product Category Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Product Categories' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'hierarchical' => true
    )
));
```

The problem is that when I go to a `product_category` archive page, for example http://example.com/dairy-industry, I get a 404. I have tried about a gajillion fixes, including

- every combination of `rewrite` arguments on the `register_taxonomy` code
- re-saving permalinks
- turning permalinks off, saving, then turning them on again
- the above, but first deleting the .htaccess file from the server
- the above, but first deleting the rewrite_rules option from the wp_options table
- having the category base and tag base option set (and blank)

I also do not have $wp_rewrite->flush_rules() anywhere in my theme.

The most frustrating thing is that at various times throughout my fixes, and with no pattern I can identify, the custom taxonomy archive pages will start working again, but the regular pages will start giving me 404s instead. They never work at the same time, and I can't figure out which steps will reproducibly make one or the other work. It seems to be totally random.

For a further bit of interestingness, when the custom taxonomy archive pages are *not* working, one of them (`dairy-industry`) redirects to the slug of a similarly-named but different (`2011/04/dairy-industry-products`) post before giving me a 404.

I'm happy to share any code that may be helpful, just ask.

**Can anyone help me figure out this perplexing conundrum?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me helped this answer: [word-press-permalinks-broken-fro-category-and-tags-404-error-page-not-found](http://www.zeitblog.com/273/internet-2/word-press-permalinks-broken-fro-category-and-tags-404-error-page-not-found/)

Simply Check your plugins and if you have “Simple Tags” or “Multipage Toolkit“ edit plugins, and replace:

```
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

with:

```
/* $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); */
```

After, go to your permlinks page and update them... twice. Worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some issues with this before. I found that if you have a custom post type with the same name as one of your page slugs, it can cause huge issues! This may be something you need to consider.

I now use a plugin to create my custom post types, as it has built in fields for the url structure. This plugin is called [CMS Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-press/).

Comment: Thanks! That's getting close. Now all the links word, both to pages and product_categories, but my product_category archive URLs appear with the taxonomy in front, like http://example.com/product_category/dairy-industry. How can I get rid of the product_category part?

Comment: Did you use CMS Press, or did you get rid of pages with the same slug names?

If you are still using your code above, try adding:
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>$slug),

I'm not sure whether youc an set that to false or not, but at lease you are able to change it. Check the codex page for it, under the rewrite argument. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this problem which only appeared after upgrading to 3.1.2 from 3.1 (we skipped 3.1.1). I get 404 response for custom post types and anywhere that a custom rewrite rule has been applied (e.g. custom feed links).

I managed to get it working reasonably well with this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wcs-custom-permalinks-hotfix/

However I still get these pages 404'ing every now and then - I suspect when a new post is added. When that happens I can get them working again by going to the permalink settings page and simply hitting save.

Be sure to check your htaccess rules - the website for the plugin has a lot of information and recommended htaccess rules for single and multisite setups:

http://wpcodesnippets.info/blog/wcs-custom-permalinks-hotfix.html

Answer (score 0):

When i first encountered this 404 issue with permalinks, I was frantic. It impacted all of my own sites and several that I manage. Hundreds of folks used a hotfix function that I'd coded ... and then responding to various special cases from users ... we perfected it to the plugin that you mention.

The original article is here:
http://wpcodesnippets.info/blog/how-to-fix-the-wp-3-1-custom-permalinks-bug.html

It is my estimation that this bug has impacted thousands of WP sites. But, the official developers have declined to address it in any subsequent updates. Fortunately, the plugin should work in perpetuity.

Regarding your occasional 404's for new posts, I'm particularly curious if you discover the culprit. Here's one thing to try. As soon as this happens with a new post, pull your site up in a browser that you don't normally use ... and see if you can click a link to the new post from there.

Certainly, older plugins that modify or access the permalink structure will need minor mods until WP decides to address the issue.

Anyway, I'm glad the plugin has helped.